# elementary OS Freya cant access internet

Tags: internet, ethernet

Good day! I'm already connected to a wired network. I can ping websites and can access router through browser. But when i try to surf it always prompt a message that i cant access internet. Can someone help me for this problem? Thank you. Sorry for my grammar and i hope you understand

Comment: can you put screenshot of error.

Comment: Change your DNS to Google